# Page navigation bar - without taking space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar which contains some useful buttons and information. I don't want it to be sticky or something like this, I just want it to be on the top.

I have a problem with the scroll appearing on my page because:

- I have this navbar
- I sometimes want to center some things on page, therefore I use tricks like `height: 100%`

The rest of the question is me explaining myself **but you can see exactly what I mean here**: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-fast-wtoc5:

- the scroll appears
- the content is not centered until I scroll

The expected output for me is: the content below the navbar takes the space it needs to the end of the page's height (without adding more height and scroll) and is centered (vertically and horizontally) - within its own div.

So let's go into the details:

This is the navbar:

```
const AppBar = styled.header`
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
`;
```

It's `styled-components` syntax but you know the drill, it's a header with this style. Anyway, this page header is rendered above anything else, it's present on every page. The problem that I have is:

When I have a page with like one `<span>` centered on it (so not too much of content), the page renders with a scroll, because the navbar has its height, so I can scroll as much as it takes to cover it up fully (and no more).

This is a problem for me since when I don't scroll, the text is not centered on the page. And if I do, then it's centered, but I don't want to have to scroll to see the desired output.

Anyway, this are my global styles:

```css
html, body, #root {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

And this is how I center text on the page (this is the style of the `div` in which `span` is put):

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
height: 100%;
```

I know I can do **position: fixed** but then if some page is not centered (its content should appear just below the navbar) then its content is getting covered by the page header.

So my question is: Is there a way to have this navbar not add a scroll to my page (I imagine it would be like painted "over" the page?) or somehow center my pages differently (when I want to) to make this centering work with the navbar present as it is now?

P.S I use React but I composed this example in plain HTML&CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified some of your code(in your link). I hope this is what you want and be helpful to you.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;             /* add this */
  flex-direction: column;    /* add this */
}

.navbar {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0.1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: sticky;
  flex-shrink: 1;           /* add this */
}

.center {
  font-size: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  flex-grow: 1;             /* add this */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar"></header>
    <div class="center">Centered content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just did exactly what you did. flexbox solves the issue completely, thank you very much anyway :) Accepting the answer

Comment: I am kinda wondering if this technique would have to be applied to every project I do, or is there a better/standard way to do so

Comment: In my knowledge, There is another way to solve it. That is using `calc()` function in css, Setting your content height with height of navbar.

You can see what is `calc()` in this url(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())